# What's the best way to make multiple draggable views programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to have many labels that are draggable and wrote the following code to make this happen. However this is a pretty dumb way to do it... Because I write a function for every object. Is there a way which can achieve the same effect using just one function?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 2 - 100, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height / 2 - 100, 100, 50))
        let label2 = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 2 - 100, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height / 2 - 200, 100, 50))

        label.text = "Str"
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        self.view.addSubview(label)

        label2.text = "ing"
        label2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label2.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        self.view.addSubview(label2)



         let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("wasDragged:"))
        label.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        label.userInteractionEnabled = true

        let gesture2 = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("wasDragged1:"))
        label2.addGestureRecognizer(gesture2)
        label2.userInteractionEnabled = true



    }

    func wasDragged(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
         let translation = gesture.translationInView(self.view)
        if let label = gesture.view {

        label.center = CGPoint(x: label.center.x + translation.x, y: label.center.y + translation.y)

        }
        gesture.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)


    }

    func wasDragged1(gesture:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let translation = gesture.translationInView(self.view)
        if let label = gesture.view {

            label.center = CGPoint(x: label.center.x + translation.x, y: label.center.y + translation.y)

        }
        gesture.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)



    }
```

Comment: Subclass UILabel and make the gesture it's property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good job for keeping the **DRY** principle!

What I would do is make a **protocol** called `Draggable` that is limited to `UIView` - since `UILabel` is a subclass of `UIView` and because you can make `UIView` draggable later if you wanted to as well.

```
protocol Draggable where Self: UIView {}
```

Then, I would make an extension to the `Draggable` protocol that contains methods such as setting the `UIPanGesture` and handling its `wasDragged` callback.

```
extension Draggable {
    // Implement things to make the view draggable
}
```

Then, I would subclass `UILabel` into a `CustomLabel` that implements the `Draggable` protocol.

```
class CustomLabel : UILabel, Draggable {
    // Customize your label here
}
```

Here, you can easily see that this custom label is a subclass of **UILabel** and most importantly, that it's **Draggable**!

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. However when I try to make the protocol with your code above I get many errors...

Comment: I got 3 errors: Statement cannot begin with a closure expression, Expected "{" in protocol type, Braced block of statements is an unused closure.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension UILabel {
    convenience init(
        text:String,
        textAlignment:NSTextAlignment,
        backgroundColor:UIColor,
        target:Any,
        action:Selector
    )
{
    self.init(frame:CGRect.zero)
    self.text = text
    self.textAlignment = textAlignment
    self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    if target != nil && action != nil {
        let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: target, action: #selector(action))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }
}
```

You can make this extension to UILabel or UIView, whichever works best for you. You can make this convenience initializer failable if you want, and add anything else to it as needed. (I prefer setting the initial frame to CGRect.zero but YMMV.)